# WinApi. Application gives wrong info about disk

Tags: c++, winapi

I wrote application which give me info about my disk. But with one exception. I keep my application on desktop `C:`. Application give me right info about `pendrive` and disk `E:`  but NOT FOR DISK `C:`. 
When I copy my application on `pendrive` and run it (from `pendrive`) - i get right info about disk C: and E: but NOT FOR PENDRIVE.

Problem is in function `GetVolumeInformation`. This function give me wrong info (only for disk which i run my application from)

```
GetVolumeInformation( ListItem, volumeNameBuffer, MAX_PATH, & volumeSerialNumber, & maximumComponentLength, & fileSystemFlags, fileSystemNameBuffer, MAX_PATH );
```

In conclusion: 
I have right info about all disk  (DISK TYPE, SIZE) 
and wrong info about parameters from GetVolumeInformation function but ONLY for disk which I run application from. 
[wrong info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2aT4.png)
[right info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV3lL.png)

Comment: What is the "wrong info"?

Comment: Ir the value of `ListItem` correct? (and with trailing \ ?).

Comment: I show it in html "wrong info". 
ListItem = "C:" or "D:" or "E:" itp. It is correct i think (i have all disk in comobox, i take choose option and write it to ListItem

Comment: So, did you debug it? Does it display the wrong info or get the wrong info from the API? Why do you think it's "wrong"? Please keep in mind we cannot "see" your disk. What is wrong about the numbers?

Comment: get the wrong info from API. 
for example. Should be NTFS: result : EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE

http://i.stack.imgur.com/w2aT4.png

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/TPD8HLj.png - u see? get wrong info

Comment: @aykax - that last image shows execution to be paused on the function call that would retrieve that info. The image isn't really useful with execution paused on this line (line 187), pause execution on the following line, so that the info has been (or at least attempted to have been) retrieved

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/8P1nh3W.png - still the same

Comment: Then, you should be capturing the (BOOL) result of this call. If the result is 0 (false), you should call `GetLastError` to find out what went wrong. It looks to me like this call is not doing anything. You can easily set the value of `volumeNameBuffer` to a known value before the call is made, with the debugger, to see if it changes - this is just a quick way of confirming that the return value will be false. (it wont require re-compilation to test)

Comment: I solved my problem. I change "C:" to "C:\\"
(form "E:" and "D:" etc working to all disk without disk which I run application from. Form with \\ works to all disk - include C.
Thanx all for help. GetLastError help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I set the ListItem var to hold "C:", the code succeeds. If I then set this var to hold "D:" it fails, with `FormatMessage` and `GetLastError` reporting: `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

If I instead set the var to hold "D:/" or "D:\\" then it succeeds. The same is true for all logical drive letters present in my system.

Having a closer look at the docs for `GetVolumeInformation`, we can see that the first parameter it expects is a string that holds *the **root directory** of the volume to be described*. Therefore, if you just pass C: or D: etc, you're passing the current directory of the drive concerned which may or may not be the root. If it's not the root, *boom*!

Also, on a side note - the volume serial number is a 32 bit number, typically displayed in hex notation. The following snippet formats it the same way that the `dir` command does.

```
printf("Vol ser#: '%X-%X'\n", (volumeSerialNumber>>16) , (volumeSerialNumber&0xFFFF) );
```

**result**
`Vol ser#: 'AA25-7CEF'`

As compared to either:

`printf("Vol ser#: '%X'\n", volumeSerialNumber );` (**result:** Vol ser#: 'AA257CEF')

or

`printf("Vol ser#: '%u'\n", volumeSerialNumber );` (**result:** Vol ser#: '2854583535')

Comment: I did it 5 min before you wrote your comment. You have a right. Thanks!

Comment: Arriving at the answer yourself is by far the best outcome, I think. Glad you got it before I wrote the solution.